# Convert Access Expression to VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, expression

GainRecDistr: IIf([BegTaxBasis]=0 And [Contribution]+[Distribution]=0,0,IIf([BegTaxBasis]=0 And [TaxIncSubTotal]=0,-[Distribution],IIf([Distribution]=0,0,IIf([TBBLL]>0,0,IIf([TBBLL]+[Recourse]+[QualifiedNonrecourse]+[NonRecourse]<[Distribution],-[Distribution],IIf([TBBLL]+[Recourse]+[QualifiedNonrecourse]+[NonRecourse]>[Distribution] And [TBBLL]+[Recourse]+[QualifiedNonrecourse]+[NonRecourse]<0 And [TaxIncSubTotal]<0,[TBBLL]+[Recourse]+[QualifiedNonrecourse]+[NonRecourse]-[TaxIncSubTotal],[TBBLL]+[Recourse]+[QualifiedNonrecourse]+[NonRecourse]))))))

when I try to calculate the above in access expression it gives me an error message saying query is too complex specifically the problem is with this section:

IIf([TBBLL]+[Recourse]+[QualifiedNonrecourse]+[NonRecourse]>[Distribution] And [TBBLL]+[Recourse]+[QualifiedNonrecourse]+[NonRecourse]<0 And [TaxIncSubTotal]<0,[TBBLL]+[Recourse]+[QualifiedNonrecourse]+[NonRecourse]-[TaxIncSubTotal],[TBBLL]+[Recourse]+[QualifiedNonrecourse]+[NonRecourse]))))))

How can I convert this into a VBA expression? Any ideas much appreciated?

Comment: How many table joins in your query? How much other sql? Can you post all of it?  Did you search for 'Access query too complex' and see their suggestions?  i.e. http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/123432-Query-is-too-complex-error-msg-what-causes

Comment: The 'query is too complex to be evaluated' is probably related to a Null value in your calculations.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA you cant use your fields like `[Field]` you reference them from the datasource like `Me!Field.Value`, the IIf works the same in vba, so to give you a example:

```
IIf(Me!BegTaxBasis = 0 AND (Me!Contribution.Value+Me!Distribution.Value) = 0,DoSomething, DoSomething )
```

With that example you should be able to build your code on your selfe.